# Which project type should I select in XCode to practice Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Which project type should I select in XCode to practice Objective-C?

I select a new project, then under "OS X" I select "Application" since this is the only place I see the "Command Line Tool" option which is appropriate for just practising the language. Now I have the following options:

1. C
2. C++
3. Core Data
4. Core Foundation
5. Core Services
6. Foundation

Well the first two don't seem appropriate, since I already know those languages.

Which should I choose? Do the last four options all encompass Objective-C? Can you give a high-level explanation of why/when I'd choose between the last four options?

Comment: What are the parameters that define "practicing" for you? You could write whatever ObjC you like in a GUI app, for example, and just let the window sit there and do nothing.

Comment: Just the Command Line Tool is fine for now, though I guess anything would work? Though maybe if I choose one with many libs/framework included I'll just be compiling a whole lot of stuff I don't need. I guess I just need a little help and guidance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Foundation option will be the most appropriate for "just to practice" Objective-C.
The material from Apple:

> The Foundation framework defines a base layer of Objective-C classes. In addition to providing a set of useful primitive object classes, it introduces several paradigms that define functionality not covered by the Objective-C language.

What about Core Foundation it was created during the transition of Mac OS to Mac OS X to help support that transition. Initially, it was done both for speed and to allow purely non-Objective-C programs to be written. Over time, that has proven to be a non-issue and CF has more and more bits that are implemented in Objective-C.

Core services are called so because they provide essential services to apps but have no direct bearing on the app’s user interface.

And finally core data framework provides generalized and automated solutions to common tasks associated with object life-cycle and object graph management, including persistence.

Answer (score 1):

You should use *Foundation.* It automatically links against the *Foundation framework* as this contains the classes, which doesn't describe user interfaces. The Foundation framework is written in ObjectiveC.

*CoreData* is also written in ObjectiveC, but is a framework for data bases.

Comment: So it's like the Objective-C classes, but without the Graphical User Interface framework bits n bobs?

Comment: Yes. If you build an iOS app you have to link additionally against UIKit for text fields, labels etc. On OS X you need additionally the AppKit for table views, windows etc.